# Comparing two columns in a data frame across many rows using R language

Tags: r, dataframe, compare

I have a data frame that I'm working within which I'd like to compare a data point `PathwayName` with  `ExpressionData`. This comparison will be done across many rows (10million+) of the data frame. Here are the first few lines of my data frame where the contents inside each row are only separated by space:

```
>View(df)

    PathwayName                                      ExpressionData 
1   41bbPathway BLACK   215538_at   210671_x_at...   215538_at  na  28.566616...
2   ace2Pathway BLACK   214533_at   215184_at...     215538_at  na  28.566616...    
3   acetPathway BLACK   215184_at   01502_s_at...    215184_at  na  4.2084746...
4   achPathway  BLACK   211570_s_at 215184_at...     215184_at  na  4.2084746...
5   hoPathway   BLACK   201968_at   214578_s_at...   201968_at  na  472.4969...
```

As a final product, I want it to compare, copy and save into a new file where the output should be like this:

```
>View(df)

    PathwayName               ExpressionData 
1   41bbPathway 215538_at     215538_at         
2   acetPathway 215184_at     215184_at 
3   achPathway  215184_at     215184_at 
4   hoPathway   201968_at     201968_at
```

This is what I had done:

```
sub("BLACK.*", "", df)
```

I know that **this doesn't work**, so I hope someone can help.
I had look into many Q&A about comparing two columns in a data frame, but I cannot follow those because, **I need to compare each contents in a rows and find any similar contents(`in this case the one with ..._at`) and not only comparing based on the columns.**

Hope someone know about this.
Thank you.

Comment: This certainly looks like a `merge` operation, although I'm guessing you don't just  want 3 columns in the output but rather want to drag along some of the other information in the matching rows. You should post `dput(head(df))`

Comment: @42- I think two columns are desired, the first column just has two terms separated by whitespace.

Comment: The OP needs to respond to both questions.

Comment: Yes, @42, you are right. I don't want 3columns in the output. I only want those two columns to be as it is but with only **two terms separated by whitespace in the 1st column** and **one term in the 2nd column**. It still should be **two columns** afterall as @steveb said. I will add it after finish running the code for `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: Its too many lines and became truncated, even after using `dput(head(df))`. Is it still useful to post here? or can I give it to you privately @42-? I really need help in this matter.

Comment: you could duplicate the Pathway name column and gsub everything after the pathway for one copy and then in the second copy use `gsub(".* BLACK +([0-9]{6}_at) .*","\\1",df$PathwayName)` then select rows where the gene names are the same

Comment: @JeremyS, I had already duplicate the PathwayName column using `df["NewPathwayName"] <- NA` `df$NewPathwayName <- df$PathwayName` but I don't understand what do you mean by gsub everything after the pathway and what is the different with the second copy? Can you explain it again?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple task, the order of _at, _x_at and _s_at genes are inconsistent and I am guessing they have differing lengths. The other assumption I make is that the `ExpressionData` only lists a single gene per line, if that is violated this will not work properly. So I would use a list rather than a data.frame as it makes comparing a bit more simple. Since we only have a snippet of the data to go by I am using only that.

```
# firstly to make the data
PathwayName <-                                       
c("41bbPathway BLACK   215538_at   210671_x_at...",
"ace2Pathway BLACK   214533_at   215184_at...",
"acetPathway BLACK   215184_at   01502_s_at...",
"achPathway  BLACK   211570_s_at 215184_at...",
"hoPathway   BLACK   201968_at   214578_s_at...")
 PathwayName <- gsub("\\.\\.\\.","",PathwayName) # you shouldn't need this, it only fixes the partial data you supplied when I copied and pasted

ExpressionData <- 
c("215538_at  na  28.566616...",
"215538_at  na  28.566616...",
"215184_at  na  4.2084746...",
"215184_at  na  4.2084746...",
"201968_at  na  472.4969...")
  ExpressionData <- gsub("\\.\\.\\.","",ExpressionData) # you shouldn't need this, it only fixes the partial data you supplied when I copied and pasted

# to compare
PNlist <- sapply(PathwayName,function(x) strsplit(x, split=" ")) # make a list from each line
PNlist <- lapply(PNlist, function(x) x[grepl("_at",x)]) # select genes
EDlist <- sapply(ExpressionData,function(x) strsplit(x, split=" "))
EDlist <- lapply(EDlist, function(x) x[grepl("_at",x)])

Result <- data.frame("PathwayName"=gsub(" BLACK.*","",PathwayName),
                     "PathwayGene"=as.character(lapply(1:length(PNlist),function(x) PNlist[[x]][PNlist[[x]] %in% EDlist[[x]]])),
                     "ExpressionData"=gsub(" .*","",ExpressionData),stringsAsFactors=F)
# this will return a 'character(0)' if PathwayName has no gene matching ExpressionData so the next line corrects for this
Result <- Result[Result$PathwayGene == Result$ExpressionData,]
```

Comment: thank you very much @JeremyS but as you said, there is a possibility that I also need  **_x_at and _s_at** genes beside this **_at**, therefore, how to add it in the `PNlist` and `EDlist`?

Comment: I ran this `Result <- data.frame("PathwayName"=gsub(" BLACK.*", "",x$PathwayName), 
                     "PathwayGene"=as.character(lapply(1:length(PNlist), function(x) PNlist[[x]][PNlist[[x]] %in% EDlist[[x]]])), 
                     "ExpressionData"=gsub(" .*","",x$ExpressionData), stringAsFactors=F)` and I got this `Error in gsub(" BLACK.*", "", x$PathwayName) : object 'x' not found`. Why is it?

Comment: oh right, remove x$ from both calls. I updated the answer.

Comment: I had removed it and got this instead `Error in data.frame(PathwayName = gsub(" BLACK.*", "", PathwayName), PathwayGene = as.character(lapply(1:length(PNlist),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 481, 22284, 1`.

Comment: That says your objects are of differing lengths, how those numbers are possible if you have a data.frame of over 10 million rows I don't know.

Comment: Before this, I used this code to merge both dataset using this `df1 <- read.table (".~/gender.gmt", header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", dec = ".", fill = TRUE)
df2 <- read.table ("~/gender.gct", header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"", dec = ".", fill = TRUE)
df <- merge(df1, df2)` and the results is those 10million rows, but I already omit this merging and by using your code, the rows are as mentioned above. therefore, how to handle those differences and still compare them?

Comment: I'm seeing a lot of red flags there. You should start by learning some basic R.

Comment: Yes, I will. Thanks a lot for your help.